The name of the user who started the process
There are several running processes with the same name, (for example: notepad.exe) and there is a PID of these processes .
import psutil
PROCNAME = "notepad.exe"
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
        print(proc)

I need to find out which network or local user the processes were running under

The username is shown in the documentation example. Is that what you want? https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.process_iter
